# DNS lookup working but nothing pinging

Tags: windows-server-2008, ping, domain-name-system

I have three forward lookup zones in my DNS server.  When I try pinging a server that's part of lookup zone A from a computer that's part of that same zone, I get a response.  If I try pinging a server that's not in the same zone as the computer I'm pinging from, I get nothing. When I try an nslookup of the servers that are not part of the same lookup zone, the names resolve correctly. If I append the domain onto the name, I can ping it just fine.

Is there a way I can fix this? or do I need to keep appending the domain onto the name if the computer I'm trying to ping is not of the same domain as me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to append the other domains in your TCP/IP properties if you wish to reach them without the FQDN.

[image]

Comment: I did that too, still no dice

Answer (score 0):

Try flushing the DNS cache and then running a network capture on the client and then run ping and nslookup. You should see the DNS queries from the client and the answers from the server, which should give you some idea to what's happening.

Comment: I've done what B. Riley said above and put those three domains in to the TCP/IP properties. When I do that, I see the DNS queries go out for server.domainA, server.domainB and server.domainC and it answers the third one with an A record. I still can't ping anything that is outside of my parent domain without using the FQDN

Comment: I see NBNS queries when I try to do a ping, but no DNS queries